# Serilog Splunk logged parameters are nested within "event"

Tags: c#, .net, splunk, serilog

Serilog with Splunk sink writes events in nested structure. It wraps my logged parameters into "events" object. While watching logs on Splunk every time I have to press on "+" to expand properties that are actually useful for me. It slows down process of analyzing logs significantly.

Example of how logs are shown:

[image]

Is there a way to affect the structure sent to Splunk, like brining everything in "event" one level up? Or maybe there's some setting which could help in Splunk itself?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be JSON structured data with an 'event' and 'time' field, which is awfully reminiscent of the structure that is used [by the 'event' endpoint version of the HTTP Event Collector in Splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.1/Data/FormateventsforHTTPEventCollector#Event_metadata).

Could it be that Serilog is sending to `hxxps://yourhechost:port/services/collector/raw` when it should be sending to `hxxps://yourhechost:port/services/collector/event` instead?

Answer (score 0):

added this to your search might help you manually look though the logs

```
|spath event
|spath input=event (this part is optional)
|table event
```